# C# Exchange Web Services Attachment Saving not working after .Net Core 3.1 Migration

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, asp.net-core-3.1

Hopefully a very simple one. I migrated an application to `.net-core` 3.1 from `.net` framework 4.7 that uses `EWS`. Other than making numerous interactions Async all seems to be working fine without any change. Apart from downloading attachments from the email. Whilst debugging and using the object examiner the `FileAttachment` object exists and the object properties/size look exactly what I expect. The `FileAttachment`.`Load`(string outputPath) creates a  file, however, the file has 0KB content size. So the shell has been created but no data has been streamed into it. Probably I'm missing something obvious but the obvious is escaping me. Tried using the stream and output path methods, the same result.  The function works fine still in the `.net` framework version. Any ideas very greatly appreciated?

```
                foreach (EmailMessage email in orderedList)
                {

                    EmailMessage message = await EmailMessage.Bind(_service, email.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));

                    if (email.HasAttachments)
                    {
                        foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
                        {
                            bool getFile = false;

                            if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                            {
                                FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) && fileAttachment.Name.StartsWith(filename))
                                {
                                    getFile = true;
                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
                                {
                                    getFile = true;
                                }

                                if (getFile)
                                {

                                    //var response = await fileAttachment.Load();

                                    //FileStream theStream = new FileStream(outputDirectory + fileAttachment.Name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                                    //fileAttachment.Load(theStream);
                                    //theStream.Close();
                                    //theStream.Dispose();

                                    fileAttachment.Load(outputDirectory + fileAttachment.Name);
                                    message.IsRead = true;
                                    await  message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, true);
                                    filepaths.Add(outputDirectory + fileAttachment.Name);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Digging into the decompiled source, it seems .Load() might need to be awaited, but it's return type is void so that's not possible.

Comment: https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api/issues/40

Comment: What is the assembly and namespace of the FileAttachment class ?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api/issues/40

```
var f1 =  await fileAttachment.Load();
 if (f1 != null)
{
  FileAttachment loaded = f1.First().Attachment as FileAttachment;
  File.WriteAllBytes(outputDirectory + fileAttachment.Name, loaded.Content);
}
```

This github comment fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the Detail From MicrosoftDoc [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-exchange-docs/blob/master/docs/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange.md)

```
foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
{

   if (attachment is FileAttachment)
   {
         FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
         DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory("absolute path");
         String name = fileAttachment.Name; 
         fileAttachment.Load("absolute path" + name);
         
                            
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that Load(string) returns void so it cannot be awaited

Try this :

```
if (getFile)
{
    fileAttachment.Load();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, fileAttachment.Name);
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileAttachment.Content);
        filepaths.Add(filePath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // write somewhere
    }
}
```